# React rendering a loop inside a loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops

Trying to loop inside a loop and getting error: value.forEach is not a function.

Dont know how to write this code inside a render

```
render(){

    return(
        Object.entries(this.props.detailOras).map(([key, value])=>{

       return(
            <div className="flex-row">
            <div className="flex-cont">
                <div>Laikas</div>
                <div>Temperatūra </div>
                <div>Vėjas</div>  
                <div>Krituliai</div>
            </div>

                {value.forEach(day => {
                    return(
                        <div className="flex-cont">
                            <div>{day.forecastTimeUtc.slice(11,16)}</div>
                                <div>{day.airTemperature} </div>
                                <div>{day.windSpeed}</div>  
                                <div>{day.totalPrecipitation}</div>
                            </div>
                          )
                })}
                     </div>
        )
                }


        ))}
```

Comment: What is the value of `this.props.detailOras`? What are the values of that object?

Comment: try this this { !value?null: value.forEach....

Comment: console.log(detailOras):


2020-05-28:
forecast: Array(7)
0: {forecastTimeUtc: "2020-05-28 17:00:00", airTemperature: 16.8, windSpeed: 5, windGust: 10, windDirection: 6, …}


1: {forecastTimeUtc: "2020-05-28 18:00:00", airTemperature: 16.4, windSpeed: 4, windGust: 9, windDirection: 4, …}
......
2020-05-29: {forecast: Array(24)}
2020-05-30: {forecast: Array(22)}

Comment: You can click on **edit** under your question to include that formatted into your question :)

Comment: {
2020:05:28:{
forecast:[
1: [ {airtemp: xx},{windspeed: xx} .....]
2:  [ {airtemp: xx},{windspeed: xx} .....]
...
]}

Answer (score 1):

Below should work provided `value` is populated as an array in later stages.

```
render(){

    return(
        Object.entries(this.props.detailOras).map(([key, value])=>{

       return(
            <div className="flex-row">
            <div className="flex-cont">
                <div>Laikas</div>
                <div>Temperatūra </div>
                <div>Vėjas</div>  
                <div>Krituliai</div>
            </div>
                {(value.forecast || []).map(day => {
                    return(
                        <div className="flex-cont">
                            <div>{day.forecastTimeUtc.slice(11,16)}</div>
                            <div>{day.airTemperature} </div>
                            <div>{day.windSpeed}</div>  
                            <div>{day.totalPrecipitation}</div>
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
))}
```